# I want to dynamically create i18n ecosystem in WordPress

Tags: localization

In WordPress,

**"**`__()`, `_e()` **etc."** I want to create an ecosystem that finds locations and automatically generates `".pot"` files.
<**Just like WPML**.>

Some research for this led me to this address [WordPress 118n](http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/tools/trunk/) "http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/tools/trunk/".

#### But I couldn't see exactly how to do **about it**.

Is there anyone who can help me how to proceed? I just want help and direction.

What I'm planning is this: To show the variables in the generated `POT` file in the panel in a writable and translatable way, just like WPML. Then compile the `PO` and `MO` files when the translations are complete.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! do you mean ([wp i18n make-pot](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/)) this? using wordpress wp-cli this is a built in option, you would first need to install [wp-cli](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/) for that

Comment: Thank you @Buttered_Toast, yes but I want to do it server side myself, not with `CLI` scripts.

Comment: Best thing I can come up with is diging in the plugin [loco translate](https://github.com/wp-plugins/loco-translate), this plugin provides an interfance for translations, both plugins and themes. It creates a .pot, .po and .mo files based on your needs. Looking at the source code give a good idea how they have done it.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast thank you I will reasearch it.